# Generating several random numbers within a range

Tags: command-line

I want to generate, say 10 random numbers between 100 and 200 (both included). How do I make it with rand?

Comment: What do you mean by `rand`? The `RANDOM` variable? `/dev/random`? `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: No, I just mean the rand command that you execute from bash.

Comment: This [`rand`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rand.1.html) or this [`rand`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rand.1ssl.html)?

Answer (score 7):

If you mean the `rand` from [the `rand` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/rand) (as opposed to the one from OpenSSL), it doesn't support a lower bound, only an upper bound. What you can do is the shift-lower-bound-to-zero-then-add-lower-bound trick:

```
$ rand -N 10 -M 100 -e -d '\n' | awk '{$0 += 100}1'
170
180
192
168
169
170
117
180
167
142
```

- `-N` is the number of random numbers you need
- `-M` would be the upper bound of the numbers `rand` outputs, so (*max* - *min* = 100)
- `-e -d '\n'` sets the delimiter to a newline. That's for convenience of processing by `awk`.

The `awk` code then takes each line and adds 100 to it.

Comment: Great, Muru. That's it! Tks a lot.

Comment: Quise decir, fantástico, Muru. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 6):

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import random
for i in range(10):
    print random.randint(100, 200)
```

**Output :**

```
187
123
194
190
124
121
191
103
126
192
```

Here I have used the `random` module of `python` to generate 10 (`range(10)`) random integers between 100 and 200 (included) (`random.randint(100, 200)`).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Perl way:

```
$ perl -le 'print 100+int(rand(101)) for(1..10)'

129
197
127
167
116
134
143
134
122
117
Or, on the same line:

$ perl -e 'print 100+int(rand(101))." " for(1..10); print "\n"'
147 181 146 115 126 116 154 112 100 116
```

You could also use `/dev/urandom` (adapted from [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/128/generating-random-numbers/)):

```
$ for((i=0;i<=10;i++)); do 
    echo $(( 100+(`od -An -N2 -i /dev/urandom` )%(101))); 
done
101
156
102
190
152
130
178
165
186
173
143
```

Comment: @ignaciocaviedes you're welcome. However, please consider [accepting](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) one of these answers (perhap's muru's which uses the tool you wanted) and upvoting the rest instead of leaving thank you comments. That's the way thanks are expressed here. Y porque le escribiste en Castellano al Muru? El tío es de India! :P

Comment: @terdon I have no idea what you just said. O.o

Answer (score 5):

With `shuf` from GNU coreutils:

```
$ shuf -i 100-200 -n 10
159
112
192
140
166
121
135
120
198
139
```

Comment: I think yours is the best answer to my question, Cuonglm. I appreciate it; thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `awk`:

```
$ awk -v min=100 -v max=200 -v freq=10 'BEGIN{srand(); for(i=0;i<freq;i++)print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}'
132
131
148
100
104
125
103
197
184
165
```

Comment: +1. No extra package installations needed for this one, and DRY parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$RANDOM`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html).

```bsh
number=0   #initialize the number
FLOOR=100
RANGE=200
while [ "$number" -le $FLOOR ]
do
  number=$RANDOM
  let "number %= $RANGE"  # Scales $number down within $RANGE.
done
echo "Random number between $FLOOR and $RANGE $number"
echo
```

Comment: It worked all right, Pabi. Tks a lot again.

Answer (score 2):

#### Bash version

Nothing spectacular - simple emulation of for loop with `i` counter and `while`. Range is set using `if . . . else . . .fi` structure. Side note: my prompt is working directory first, then the input area, so don't get confused on what you see

```
$ ./bashRadom.sh 100 200                                                       
190
111
101
158
171
197
199
147
142
125
```

`bashRadom.sh`:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

i=0; 
while [ $i -lt 10  ]; do 

  NUM=$RANDOM; 
  if [ $NUM -gt $1 ] && [ $NUM -lt $2  ]; then 
      echo $NUM; 
  else continue; 
  fi;
  i=$((i+1));

done
```

#### C Version

This is the code I've been using while taking C class at my university. Small edit that I've added to fit this question is use of command line arguments (instead of hardcoding values into the source)

```
$ gcc randfunc.c   
$ ./a.out 100 200
100 
106 
155 
132 
161 
130 
110 
195 
105 
162 
187
```

`randfunc.c`:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int randInt (int, int);

void
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{    
  int min = atoi (argv[1]), max = atoi (argv[2]), i = 0;
  srand (time (NULL));    

  for (i; i < 11; i++)
    {
      printf ("%d \n", randInt (min, max));
    }    
}    

int
randInt (int a, int b)
{
  int randValue;
  randValue = a + (int) rand () % (b - a + 1);
  return randValue;    
}
```

Comment: Quite similar: http://askubuntu.com/a/621557/158442

Comment: @muru Didn't see someone already posted that.  I'm in the process of adding my C version as well. Would it be fine if I keep bash version in addition to C ?

Comment: Fine by me, either way.

Comment: If you're going to use C, you should really use C++ with the `random` library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19728404/2072269, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19666713/2072269

Comment: @muru I am not familiar with C++, only with basic C so far. But thank you for the info ^_^